Other than DMRG, what's the advantage of representing operator in MPO form?
I have been working with density matrix renormalization group (DMRG) (which a numerical method based on tensor network to find ground state energy), but I don't really get that, other than doing DMRG, what else the matrix product operator (MPO) (which is a tensor network where each tensor has two external, uncontracted indices as well as two internal indices contracted with neighboring tensors in a chain-like fashion) can do? For example, we can write Hamiltonian in second quantization form or Pauli form. They either make it easy for quantum computing community or has a compact form with physical meaning. Then, what's the advantage of MPO?

Please consider spelling out acronyms the first time even if you consider that people should know them, it really helps add clarity to your question.

-1 I have no idea what either acronym means, despite having a Ph.D. in physics, so as far as I’m concerned your question is unclear.

Yes, please, do explain your acronyms, at least for this aging mathematician with an interest in physics. :)

Hi guys, thank you for your feedback, I just edited it. Let me know if there is anything still unclear! Ans thanks John Rennie to help me edit this question!

Your question is still unclear. What is it you want to know about MPOs, in which context?
